# Jasmine: Stub ajax request with a variable URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery, jasmine-ajax

Using Jasmine (with [jasmine-ajax](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax)), I need to stub an ajax request wherein the URL has a dynamically generated parameter. Example:

```
jasmine.Ajax
  .stubRequest('search?generatedParameter=...')
  .andReturn({responseText: '...'});
```

However, Jasmine doesn't seem to allow wildcards in the URL.

**Question: Is there any way using Jasmine to stub an ajax request for a variable URL?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the `response` method to trigger a response for the most recent ajax request:

```
  jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().response({responseText: '...', status: 200});
```

Answer (score 3):

Jasmine-ajax allows a regex to be passed for the url:

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest(/search\?generatedParameter=.+/);
```

See https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax (under the Complex Requests heading) for more info.